# Conditional formatting for merged cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016, conditional-formatting

I have these two rules for a set of cells:

[image]

The full formulas are

```
=$AB27=""
```

and

```
=LOWER($AB27)=ok
```

I thought this would make it so that if "ok" (with any capitalization) was entered into the the merged cell, the cell would turn green, but apparently not:

[image]

How would I have to adjust my conditional formatting to get the results I want, i.e. the merged cell turning green if "ok" is entered into it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the Question is written, the obvious reason for failure is the second condition's text formula:

```
=LOWER($AB27)=ok
```

Notice that, as the `ok` is NOT in quotes (`"ok"`), Excel will treat it as a Named Range which does not exist and the text formula will result in `FALSE`. The condition's format will then NOT trigger and so the result described in the Question.

Further evidence that the text of the Question is not a simple mistake/oversight/typo with a deeper reason underlying the failure is given by **Máté Juhász** in his failure to be able to reproduce the error seen, instead seeing success. That is because he made no typo.

This is a difficulty with the Conditional Formatting tools. One cannot see the actual result of the test formula in place in the tools. So if typing the formula inside the CF functionality, a typo will very often go unnoticed.

Whenever possible, even for pretty simple rules, I prefer building the test formula outside the CF functionality, even if 20 formulas not just one, and copying and pasting them in as I go back and forth, no matter how obnoxious that is. It also saves me from careless, and similarly unnoticed, errors with relative addressing. Well, does half that job anyway, but that's a step up from what the CF tools provide.

Answer (score -1):

I've tried to replicate your situation but the same just works for me. Maybe you have some space entered in the cells too?

Also, you can do the same in a more simple way: generally text comparison in Excel is case-insensitive, also it formats the whole merged cells as if it would be just a single one, so you can do this too:
[image]